# Drag and drop files from sharepoint explorer view to Outlook Issue

Tags: outlook

When I open my SharePoint document library in explorer view and drag and drop my file into outlook, am getting the below pop up and after a minute the outlook hangs. Say I get this error in SysA

[image: Pop-up in outlook]

My file size is 10MB and I could drag and drop the same file from a different computer say SysB at the same time. 
When I try after sometime from SysA am able to drag and drop successfully. 
This problem do not exists all times and I keep getting it only in SysA. 
I wish to understand the root cause of the problem and if there is any fix.

As far as I googled, I could see the issue in drag & drop from IE directly and could not find any for drag and drop from explorer view of sharepoint.
I could infer that the issue is because of my Windows. But am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid transfer issues between Outlook and SharePoint & O365 I recommend using 3rd party Outlook addins such as:

- Colligo; or
- OnePlaceMail

Such addins allow you to quickly attach files from SharePoint while you're composing your email. They additionally allow you to easily file emails & attachments for handover when you leave the organisation you work for.

To attempt to resolve your current issue. I recommend checking that your firewall or AV software on the computer is not blocking the file transfer. "Explorer view" uses the WebDAV protocol to transfer files between your computer and SharePoint/O365.